# PDO Error 42000 on update

Tags: php, mysql, sql, oop, pdo

I get a PDO Error info 42000

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE id='4'' at line 15
```

I have no idea why, I tried escaping the columns and the table name with backticks as I read in other questions regarding this issue, but this didn't help.

Here is my SQL statment:

```
private function _update()
{
    $sql = 'UPDATE projects SET
    name=:name,
    client=:client,
    createDate=:createDate,
    timestamp=:timestamp,
    url=:url,
    localUrl=:localUrl,
    budget=:budget,
    payoff=:payoff,
    estimated_time=:estimated_time,
    tasksDuration=:tasksDuration,
    currentStundenlohn=:currentStundenlohn,
    tagPercentage=:tagPercentage,
    tagCategoryPercentage=:tagCategoryPercentage,
    WHERE id=:id';
    $abfrage = self::$db->prepare($sql);
    $abfrage->execute($this->toArray());
    pdo_error($abfrage);
}
```

Do you see the possible problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove last extra comma `,`.

```
$sql = 'UPDATE projects SET
    name=:name,
    client=:client,
    createDate=:createDate,
    timestamp=:timestamp,
    url=:url,
    localUrl=:localUrl,
    budget=:budget,
    payoff=:payoff,
    estimated_time=:estimated_time,
    tasksDuration=:tasksDuration,
    currentStundenlohn=:currentStundenlohn,
    tagPercentage=:tagPercentage,
    tagCategoryPercentage=:tagCategoryPercentage // From here
    WHERE id=:id';
```

Comment: spotted well. Jetzt kannst dein Tag genießen Sebsemillia.